# Get the url from device default browser in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, browser

I am working on a background application in which I need to get some device events of normal device functionality. Regarding which I need to get the URL which a user hit in device default browser.
Means if a user use blackberry device default browser to open a url, I want to retrieve that url programmetically in my application running in background.

Is this possible, please let me know with your suggestions.

Comment: Hi @samintechvalens am also searching for the same... Did you solve this..? If you got solution for this can you help me... thanQ.

Comment: Not yet, but when ever I get it, i will surely provide that answer to stack.

Answer (score 1):

There is no BlackBerry API to get the URL opened in the browser, nor is there one to access browser history.

You can add an ApplicationMenuItem to the browser application.  When the user clicks on it your application is passed the URL of the current page.